# How do I exclude middle image widths in pure CSS?

Tags: css

I'm looking for nearly the opposite of clamp in order to set an image width. An example of clamp would be:

`max-width: clamp(75%, auto, 100%);`

meaning use the native image size, but no more than 100% width and no less than 75% width.

But I'm looking for something closer to the opposite:

- If the native size of the image is 75% or less of the available
  container width, use the native image size.
- If the native size of the image
  is more than 75% of the available width but less than 100%, use 75%
  of the available width.
- If the native size of the image is 100% or
  more of the available width, use 100% of the available width.

Is this possible with CSS and no JavaScript?